# Documents needed for French Circulation visa for a new resident in UK, and where to submit them

Tags: schengen-visas, france, applications, multiple-entry, monaco

I am a new resident in UK with an Indian passport. I have been in the UK for less than an year and I've only recently started working here for the first time, so don't have local savings to show if needed. My local bank account is also new i.e. less than 2 months old. Though I do have foreign personal bank accounts that can show consolidated funds amounting to at least 30K Euros.

My firm wants me to get a circulation visa so I can attend business meetings in our Monaco Head Office multiple times in the coming year(s). The firm is a startup and had only Europeans on staff before me, so they don't know how this is done.

As this is my first Schengen visa application I am unsure of what I have got to do to submit the documents to the French Consulate during the application. The online French visa application portal wasn't the best resource to help me so I came here for advice.

1. What documents should my firm give me to assist with the application? For example,  do  I need  to get an invitation letter detailing the nature of the business work I need to do in Monaco over the coming years.
2. As this application is for business travel, do I have to submit my personal bank statements? Or is my payslip good enough?

Comment: While you might get some good advice on here, this is something your employer should be helping with and they should be your first point of contact.

Comment: Ideally you are right but the firm I work for is a startup and had only Europeans on staff. So they never had a situation like this till now. So I am on my own with completing the  application. They said they will reimburse the costs and will provide any documentations needed. But the application process they have no idea what to do.

Comment: Are the multiple meetings already scheduled?  As to your being on your own and their being willing to reimburse costs, does that include willingness to hire a French immigration lawyer to handle the application?  It's probably not necessary to do so, but if they have the money for it it would make your life somewhat easier.  A company that has "no idea what to do" simply hasn't hired the right person.

Comment: Your employer, on whose behalf you will be going to France, should write a 'To whome it may concern' letter explaining what exactly you will be doing in their Monaco Head Office, how often and how long per year, and that they will will be paying all expenses. In that way the French consulate will know exactly what type of visa is required.